# Avoid <script> tag and alert { } through regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to show message-1 "Script tag and alert are not allowed message" if regular expression matches `<Script>` tag or alert () with parenthesis. And show different message-2 "welcome" if there is only alert or script.

Show message-1 for following condition:

```
1) <script>
2) <  script >
3) < script > script
4) <  script > alert
5) < script> alert (  )
6) alert alert( )
7) alert () script
8) alert <  script >
```

show message-2 for following condition:

```
1) script script
2) alert alert
3) script alert
4) alert alert script script
5) alert script script
```

I tried <\s*[script\S*\s*]+ | \s*alert\s*\(\s*(.*?)\). But it is not satisfying all the condition. Please help me.

Comment: Your title reads `alert {}` (curly brackets) whereas there are no curly brackets in your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex: `<\s*script\s*>|alert\s*\(\s*\)`

**Test**

```
private static void test(String input) {
    String regex = "<\\s*script\\s*>|alert\\s*\\(\\s*\\)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("#1  " + input);
    } else {
        System.out.println("#2  " + input);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
#1  <script>
#1  <  script >
#1  < script > script
#1  <  script > alert
#1  < script> alert (  )
#1  alert alert( )
#1  alert () script
#1  alert <  script >
#2  script script
#2  alert alert
#2  script alert
#2  alert alert script script
#2  alert script script
```

Comment: I thought he was trying to distinguish between the two conditions - so your regex would fit for the `message 1`. But I can be wrong of course.

Comment: @Jan OP listed 8 examples of input that should "Show message-1", and 5 examples that should "show message-2", by using a regex. Code shows regex that will match first 8 examples, and shows how to use it. I then tested with all 13 examples to verify that result was as requested, and *it is*.

Comment: It certainly does, but in your second branch (`#2`) there could as well be no alerts and scripts at all and it would work nevertheless (and incorrectly output them).

Comment: @Jan Depends on how you read the question. It's not entirely clear whether #2 is the opposite of #1 (my interpretation), or if there is a #3 (your interpretation). We'll see if OP clarifies. Either way, the complex regex has been given in both our answers.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but the above regex is not working for "script alert{} alert" and "script <script>" Below is the code:
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Testing {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String regx = "<\\s*script\\s*>|alert\\s*\\{\\s*\\}";
  String myLine = "script alert{} alert";
  if(Pattern.matches(regx, myLine)){
   System.out.println("Script tag and alert are not allowed message");
   
  }else {
   System.out.println("Welcome");
  }
 }

}

Comment: This is not working for multiple script. Like : <script> script or script <script> or combination of script and alert like : script alert{} alert.

Comment: @SuryaGupta Please actually look at my example. I use `find()`, not `matches()`.

Answer (score 0):

For your message 1 part (Demo on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sE1vH1/1)):

```
(<\s*script\s*>)|(alert\s*\(\s*\))
```

For your message 2 part (Demo on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sE1vH1/2)) as simple as:

```
(script|alert)
```

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis, except of course for the two escaped ones.